# Number of vertex pairs with two edge disjoint paths between them

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, path

I am currently working on an algorithm that counts the number of pairs of vertices that have at least two edge disjoint paths between them in a multigraph. The algorithm works fine by finding the biconnected graphs, but i have a problem when a vertex connects two different biconnected grapth, like in a hour-glass graph. Furthermore, two vertices may have as many different edges between them as possible.

Comment: Could you give a specific example of a graph where your algorithm doesn't work? I feel like you should be able to duplicate those bridge vertices, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the bridge edges from the graph (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory) ), then in each remaining connected component, every vertex has at least two edge disjoint paths to every other one.

The total number of such pairs is the sum of all n(n-1)/2, where n is the number of vertexes in each of those connected components.